# Using d3.js to create multi-line chart from csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm try to create a multi-line chart with my csv file.
The content of csv file look like this:

`date,A,B
100,1,0
101,2,0
102,3,0
103,4,0
104,5,0
105,6,1
106,7,2
107,8,3
108,9,4
109,10,5
110,11,6`

And first I'm trying to create them separately

```
//This is for the line A    
    var lineGen = d3.svg.line()  
                    .x(function(d) {
                      return xScale(d.date);
                    })
                    .y(function(d) {
                      return yScale(d.A);
                    })
                    .interpolate("basis");
//This is for the line B
    var lineGen2 = d3.svg.line()
                     .x(function(d) {
                       return xScale(d.date);
                     })
                     .y(function(d) {
                       return yScale(d.B);
                     })
                     .interpolate("basis");

var data = d3.csv("new_test2.csv", function(data) {
             vis.append('svg:path') 
               .attr('d', lineGen(data))  //This is for the line A
               .attr('stroke', 'green')
               .attr('stroke-width', 2)
               .attr('fill', 'none');

             vis.append('svg:path')
                .attr('d', lineGen2(data))  //This is for the line B
                .attr('stroke', 'blue')
                .attr('stroke-width', 2)
                .attr('fill', 'none');
             });
```

It work well!
But obviously most of the codes is **too redundant** cause they're just doing the same thing with different column. 
I wonder whether there is a way to access each column one by one and plot a different line of it?

For now I'm trying to use the JavaScript function to handle the argument:

```
function draw_line(c, data){
                    console.log(c);  
                    var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
                        .x(function(d) {
                            return xScale(d.date);
                        })
                        .y(function(d) {
                            console.log(d[c]);
                            return yScale(d[c]);
                        })
                        .interpolate("basis");
                    lineGen(data); 
                };
var data = d3.csv("new_test2.csv", function(data) {
                    vis.append('svg:path')
                    .attr('d', draw_line('A', data))
                    .attr('stroke', 'green')
                    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
                    .attr('fill', 'none');

                    vis.append('svg:path')
                    .attr('d', draw_line('B', data))
                    .attr('stroke', 'blue')
                    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
                    .attr('fill', 'none');
                });
```

But it won't print out any line, but when checking the returned value with `console.log`, everything seems totally fine.
what's going wrong here? Please help :'(

Thanks for every answer provided!

*(For the `vis.append part` I probably are going to use for-loop to go through all the column, but I'm not sure how to handle the color -- to make each line show in different color-- so I haven't work on this part yet)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function draw_line(c, data){
                    console.log(c);  
                    var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
                        .x(function(d) {
                            return xScale(d.date);
                        })
                        .y(function(d) {
                            console.log(d[c]);
                            return yScale(d[c]);
                        })
                        .interpolate("basis");
                    lineGen(data); // this line should be return
                };
```

change it to

```
return lineGen(data);
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer!